# jQuery ajax success not work in codeigniter

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I had a problem with ajax. The trick is, when user click on the top hyperlink, it will send the link id through onclick=getChildMenuLink(str). Then from getChildMenuLink(str) function, it will send the str to the controller (to set the session) thru ajax. here is the code.

html code

```
<a href="http://localhost/ejournal/index.php/sysconfig" onclick="getChildMenuLink(1)">Administrator</a>

<a href="http://localhost/ejournal/index.php/welcome" onclick="getChildMenuLink(22)">Home</a>
```

jquery ajax

```
function getChildMenuLink(str) {
        'use strict';


        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "http://localhost/ejournal/index.php/sysconfig/getLink/" + str,
            success: function () {} // End of success function of ajax form           
        });  // End of ajax call

        //alert(document.URL);    
    }
```

codeigniter controller

```
function getLink($id='')
{
    $this->session->unset_userdata('parentLink'); 
    $this->session->set_userdata('parentLink',$id);
}
```

if i uncomment the alert() function on that script, it work. the PHP session is properly set. please help me

Comment: try with the ajax call synchronized.. the alert is probably helping the request complete.

Comment: please help. i'm totaly newbie.

Answer (score 3):

One problem is that in your ajax call you have `success: loadUrl()`.  This is probably not what you meant; the value that follows `success` is meant to be a function, but `loadUrl()` is not a function, it's a call to a function.  (I say probably not what you want because the only situation this would work is if `loadUrl` is a function that returns a function.)

Probably what you really want is

```
success: loadUrl
```

(no parentheses) or, perhaps more explicitly,

```
success: function() { loadUrl(); }
```

Edited to add:

OK, apparently that wasn't it.  Next thing to try: in addition to your success callback, add an error callback, so we can see if there's an error occurring:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "http://localhost/ejournal/index.php/sysconfig/getLink/" + str,
        success: function () {alert("success!")},
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { alert(textStatus + " " + errorThrown) }           
    });
```

Comment: i tried both, still no luck. Thank for helps. I,m qite new to jquery ajax

Comment: OK, added another thing to try.

Comment: The code provided me success if running on IE but the PHP session still not set. But it provided me error alert box if running on chrome. The error message is 'error'. Nothing much can help from that error message